# jQuery toggleClass to reveal panel. Close by clicking on body or anywhere onscreen

Tags: jquery

I have a simple reveal panel appearing using toggleClass and toggling class 'active' to reveal panel. Once panel is revealed i'd also like the option to 'untoggle' and remove class 'active' to hide the panel by clicking anywhere on the body.

Here's my jQuery

```
 $(".number-people .trigger").click(function(){
    $(".number-people-popup").toggleClass("active");
});
```

I've tried doing

```
 $("body").click(function(){
    $(".number-people-popup").removeClass("active");
});
```

But it always clashes. I'm sure there's a simple way of doing this.

Here's a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alexgomy/8r0Lkj2b/4/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's very quickly:

```js
$('html').click(function() {
 $(".number-people-popup").removeClass("active")
 });

$(".number-people .trigger").on('click', function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
  $(".number-people-popup").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.trigger{cursor:pointer;}

.number-people-popup{display:none;border:1px solid #000;padding:30px;width:150px;text-align:center;}
.active{display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="number-people">
    <p class="trigger">
     Click to trigger
    </p>
</div>

<div class="number-people-popup">
Reveal panel here
</div>


<br><br><br><br><br>
Once triggered i want to close by clicking anywhere in the background.

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. stopPropagation()  was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to stop event bubbling

**Edit**
Included `<select>` within collapsed `div` to reflect question on comments

```js
$(".number-people .trigger").click(function(e) {
  $(".number-people-popup").toggleClass("active");

  e.stopPropagation();
});

$("body").click(function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass("number-people-popup") && $(e.target).parents(".number-people-popup").length === 0) {
    $(".number-people-popup").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.number-people-popup {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number-people">
  <p class="trigger">
    Click to trigger
  </p>
</div>

<div class="number-people-popup">
  Reveal panel here
   <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>


<br><br><br><br><br> Once triggered i want to close by clicking anywhere in the background.
```

Comment: Explaining upon this do you know how i could have dropdowns in the reveal panel that can be selected without closing the reveal?

Comment: @alexgomy you can do it by checking if the clicked element it's the div or any of it's children, if neither it's true then remove the class, `e.target` it's the clicked element `if (!$(e.target).hasClass("number-people-popup") && $(e.target).parents(".number-people-popup").length === 0)`